# Snowflake odbc error while loading in informatica

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica

I am getting a the below error when loading a snowflake table using ODBC, any help appreciated

```
WRT_8229    Database errors occurred: 
FnName: Execute -- [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://xxxxxxdev.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/queries/v1/query-request?requestId=deed9c65-c4be-4d10-a6ec-ce042682168e&request_guid=b4684834-6373-411c-957a-e89f1110014f failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=400.
    
FnName: Execute -- [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Function sequence error
```

Comment: I've only seen this error a couple times, often because some SQL functions have to be called in a specific order and when they are not, an error is returned.  You may wish to contact Informatica Support and possibly Snowflake Support as well to analyze this (in addition to any logs you can pull).  If Informatica/client is sending functions in the wrong order, then the ODBC driver is returning the error as expected. 

Hope it helps. All I can think of since I don't see the error too much and there's not a lot of additional info to go off of here.

Comment: Seems to me its `HTTP error 400` so i assume Informatica cant reach the URL. You can test your connection using ODBC utilities(`ssgodbc -d <DSN value in odbc.ini>-u <username> -p <password> -v
`). Did you try it ? If yes and its working then, can you pls check if you can read from it? If yes, then its access issue and your user does not have write permission.